# Почему клетки в игре Жизнь всегда умирают?

Tags: javascript

[Сама игра жизнь](https://jsfiddle.net/kpgjzbht/)

```js
class ConfigField {
  constructor(){
    this.canvas =document.querySelector('#canvas');
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.array = [];
    let timer;
    this.timer = timer;
    this.generatePlayingField();
    this.canvas.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
      this.clickCanvasEvent(e);
    });
    this.drawGrid();
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click',()=>this.startLife());
    document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click',()=>this.stopLife());

  }
  generatePlayingField() {
    const n = 50, m = 50;
    for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      this.array[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        this.array[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  clickCanvasEvent(event) {
    let x = event.offsetX;
    let y = event.offsetY;
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    x = Math.floor(x/10);
    y= Math.floor(y/10);
    this.array[x][y]=1;
    console.log(this.array);
    this.drawField();
  }
  drawGrid(){
    for (let x = 0.5; x < 500; x += 10) {
      this.context.moveTo(x, 0);
      this.context.lineTo(x, 500);
    }

    for (let y = 0.5; y < 500; y += 10) {
      this.context.moveTo(0, y);
      this.context.lineTo(500, y);
    }
    this.context.strokeStyle = '#888';
    this.context.stroke();
  }
  drawField(){
    this.context.clearRect(
      0, 0, 500, 500,
    );
    this.drawGrid();
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        if(this.array[i][j]==1){
          this.context.fillStyle = 'green';
          this.context.fillRect(
            i*10,j*10,10,10,
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
  startLife(){
    // start gameOfLife
    const array2=[];
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      array2[i]=[];
      for (let j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        let neighbors = 0;
        const isCellAlive = array2[i][j];
        /* if (this.array[(i)-1][j]==1) neighbors++;// up
        if (this.array[i][(j)+1]==1) neighbors++;// right
        if (this.array[(i)+1][j]==1) neighbors++;// bottom
        if (this.array[i][(j)-1]==1) neighbors++;// left
        if (this.array[(i)-1][(j)+1]==1) neighbors++;
        if (this.array[(i)+1][(j)+1]==1) neighbors++;
        if (this.array[(i)+1][(j)-1]==1) neighbors++;
        if (this.array[(i)-1][(j)-1]==1) neighbors++;*/
        if (this.array[ConfigField.fpm(i) - 1][j] == 1) neighbors++;// up
        if (this.array[i][ConfigField.fpp(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;// right
        if (this.array[ConfigField.fpp(i) + 1][j] == 1) neighbors++;// bottom
        if (this.array[i][ConfigField.fpm(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;// left
        if (this.array[ConfigField.fpm(i) - 1][ConfigField.fpp(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (this.array[ConfigField.fpp(i) + 1][ConfigField.fpp(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (this.array[ConfigField.fpp(i) + 1][ConfigField.fpm(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (this.array[ConfigField.fpm(i) - 1][ConfigField.fpm(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        // rules
        if (isCellAlive) {
          if (neighbors < 2) {
            array2[i][j] = 0;
          } else if (neighbors === 2 || neighbors === 3) {
            array2[i][j] = 1;
          } else if (neighbors > 3) {
            array2[i][j] = 0;
          }
        } else if (neighbors === 3) {
            array2[i][j] = 1;
          }
      }
    }
    this.array = array2;
    this.drawField();
    let count=0;
    count++;
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = count;
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.startLife.bind(this), 300);
  }
  stopLife(){
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }
  static fpm(i){
    if(i==0) return 50;
    else return i;
  }
  static fpp(i){
    if(i==49) return -1;
    else return i;
  }
}

const test = new ConfigField();
console.log(test);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  #canvas {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 3px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
      <div id="count"></div>
      <button id="start">Start</button>
      <button id="stop">Stop</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А где хоть одна живая клетка в начале?

Comment: @Эникейщик, самостоятельно кликом установите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что из-за `if (isCellAlive)` изменения применяются только к тем клеткам, которые в текущем ходе живые, а у них два исхода - остаться в живых или умереть. Неживые клетки игнорируются, поэтому ожить не могут. Поэтому живых клеток становится меньше и меньше, а новых живых не появляется. Нужно смотреть соседей у всех клеток, а не только у живых. Этот блок

```
 if (isCellAlive) { // <= проблема из-за этого условия
          if (neighbors < 2) {
            array2[i][j] = 0;
          } else if (neighbors === 2 || neighbors === 3) {
            array2[i][j] = 1;
          } else if (neighbors > 3) {
            array2[i][j] = 0;
          }
        } else if (neighbors === 3) {
            array2[i][j] = 1;
          }
      }
```

нужно изменить так:

```
if (neighbors < 2) {
    array2[i][j] = 0;
} else if (neighbors === 2 || neighbors === 3) {
    array2[i][j] = 1;
} else if (neighbors > 3) {
    array2[i][j] = 0;
}
```

Последняя ветка `else if (neighbors === 3)` тоже не нужна, т.к. такое условие уже есть раньше.